# JPA Entity Class using class object as parameter

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship

I have a class **User** which has a parameter of another class type **ShoppingList**.
As this...

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String Name;
    @?????
    private ShoppingList[] shoppingList;
}
```

How can i make this ManyToOne relationship while the variable being an array?
The idea is to have a User table and another ShoppingList table, so the user can have multiple lists at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the correct way:

One `Employee` has many `ShoppingList`s.

One `ShoppingList` has only one `Employee`.

```java
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ShoppingList> shoppingList;

    ....
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ShoppingList implements Serializable {
    ....
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;

   ....
}
```

You can fine-tune your entities as per your need.
For more info, I would refer to [this tutorial](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-one-to-many-mapping), it has helped me a lot.